# Does vert.x provide any approach to load localization files? Like locale resolver?

Tags: localization, internationalization, locale, vert.x

I am new to vert.x and trying a poc to find a way to load the messages_XX.properties file into my application for localization.

I have tried using https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_localization example to get the locales from accept-language header successfully from routing context. But I am not able to find any help where to load the resource bundle files and how to fetch it with vert.x approach.

Any help or pointers would be of great help.

> router.route().handler(x->{
>             System.out.println("----accept headers-------"+x.preferredLocale());        });

What should i do next after i get user preferred locale?

Comment: Have you tried the ResourceBundle API? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html